# Getting an error when trying to handle calendar popup

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to handle a calendar popup and then getting an error.
It's unable to click on the date.

Code that I have used is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bidExpirationDate']")).click();
List<WebElement> alldates=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@role='gridcell']"));
System.out.println("All date: "+alldates.size());
for(WebElement d:alldates)
{
    String date=d.getText();
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase("21"))
    {
        d.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Output: All date: 42

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [JavaScript Error: "b.elementFromPoint is not a function" {file: "file:///C:/Users/Office/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2113754378902429082webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 11130}]'
[JavaScript Error: "b.elementFromPoint is not a function" {file: "file:///C:/Users/Office/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2113754378902429082webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 11130}]' when calling method: [wdIMouse::click]   
Command duration or timeout: 58 milliseconds
```

How i can resolve this error?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: @DebanjanB Please look into HTMl code Here is HTML Code :<table class="days weeks" role="grid" xpath="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
<th aria-label="weekday">Sun
          </th><th aria-label="weekday">Mon
          </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr>
        
<td role="gridcell">
          <span bsdatepickerdaydecorator="" ng-reflect-day="[object Object]" class="disabled">1</span>

Comment: Instead of a comment you need to update the actual question with the HTML for proper analysis